# Postfix alias not working

Tags: email, postfix, alias

I have postfix to send mail using gmail. I have aliases set but things aren't working right

if I send mail to someone at `gmail.com` it works

crontab with `MAILTO=root` sends mail via gmail relay to account `root@cmforester.com`

if I send mail to `mail@cmforester.com` using `mail -s "Test subject" mail@cmforester.com <textfile`, it works and sends via gmail relay (I get email at `mail@cmforester.com`)

but if I send mail using `mail -s "Test subject" root <textfile` it tries to get gmail to send mail via gmail relay to `root@mail` even though alias is set to `mail@cmforester.com`

hostname is `mail`
mailname is `cmforester.com` (`/etc/mailname`)

**/etc/aliases:**

```
postmaster: mail@cmforester.com  
root: mail@cmforester.com  
www-data: mail@cmforester.com  
clint: mail@cmforester.com
```

**main.cf:**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost
mydomain = cmforester.com
myhostname = mail.cmforester.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: Did you run `newaliases`?

Comment: Thank you so much, I ran new aliases but it couldn't resolve "mail" so I looked in my hosts file and added "mail" next to "localhost" and that fixed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by NerdOfLinux I ran new aliases but it couldn't resolve "mail" so I looked in my hosts file and added "mail" next to "localhost" and that fixed it. I previously ran `newaliases` but then made some changes to the `main.cf` file and my hostname/domainname which I believe made my aliases become problematic

Answer (score 0):

Editing:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

and changing:

```
myorigin = $mydomain
```

to:

```
myorigin = $myhostname
```

resolved the problem for me in that it:

- Prevented the unexpected conversion of recipient `root` to `root@$mydomain`; and
- Got my `/etc/aliases` forwarding working to the remote address I need

I won't pretend to be sure but my assumption is the following:

When a recipient without @somedomain.com is used ie. `root`, then postfix conceptually automatically appends `@[myorigin parameter value]`

if `[myorigin parameter value]` is identified as the local host, which `$myhostname` would be, then postfix knows it is destined for a local user and thus references /etc/aliases for the mapping.

Following the above logic, using `$mydomain` doesn't match the local host and is therefore assumed to be a remote address ie. `root@$mydomain` and  so `/etc/aliases` gets ignored (as it is only applied to local server users)

Comment: Almost. `@myorigin` is appended by `append_at_myorigin`, which is enabled by default. Mails are identified as local by the `mydestination` list of domains.

Comment: thanks @Maxxer - very interesting! I will certainly take a look at this and see if I can get it working in my use case